Sites 10 | Experience Space Extension - ItemSelector
Sites 10 Experience space UI - Extension requirement: In Tinymce editor, onclick of menu button a customized Modal will open with option to browse items (ItemSelector capability to select the items).
We found useItemSelector hook is available in '@tridion-docs/extensions' but not in tridion-sites/extensions packages.
Do we need to implement our own ItemSelector dialog component(react component) in sites 10 experience space UI to use in custom extensions ?
Any suggestions to integrate ItemSelector dialog.
Thanks in advance.

Our current version of @tridion-docs/extensions doesn't expose built-in ItemSelector component.
In the coming release we're adding support for opening built-in Modal component where you can get additional input from the user, this way you can also implement item selector.
We are taking notes to prioritize new features / improvements to existing API. Adding ItemSelector will be considered in the future releases to make developer's life easier.

Yevhen, Thank you for the details. Any tentative Tridion Sites version to include ItemSelector in experience space extension ?

I don't have any dates, we are planning big refactoring of item selector to make it's api user-friendly and ready to be public. Only after that we will start exposing component to extension framework.
